# after setting the SetView my map does not change

Tags: windows-runtime, bing-maps

I'm working on a windows store app and have the following code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    myMap.SetView(_lastLocation, 10.0);
}
```

the problem is, when I start the app, I still see the default view and its not centered to the `_lastLocation` and also the zoom level is not set to 10.

when I debug it, `_lastLocation` is not null and the code in the OnNavigatedTo is reached.

Why I dont see it?

Comment: try `Loaded` event of `Page`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Loaded` event of `Page`. It will solve the problem.